# JSP MYSQL Hide Same Number and show letter

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am a newbie still learning jsp and mysql.
I have a database with following table fields:

```
id   no letter content
1    1         book
2    2         pen
3    3  a      apple
4    3  b      mango
5    3  c      banana
6    4         car
```

I need somebody help me, how can I do a query in jsp with mysql so the result will be like this?

```
 No   Content
1.    book
2.    pen
3. a  apple 
   b  mango
   c  banana
4.    car
```

Comment: Your result doesn't look right. You should have three columns (`no`, `letter` and `content`) in your query. If you want to drop `no` for `mango` and `banana`, you need to do it when you present the data. But dropping actual content of `no` column for them makes no sense.

Comment: Is it not possible to merge the no and letter query in one column? Seems the code tag is not like what I want in mobile browser. I want to put screenshot but my reputation must ten :(